# Display invoice in 3 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with invoice in Oracle database. I will need to select invoice_id column from invoice in 3 column ordered by data_creation.

Result should be like under

```
invoie_id invoie_id  invoie_id
1          2          3
4          5          6
...
```

Comment: can you show your data and what you have tried so far please

Comment: Double self outer join, modulo 3 in where clause.

Comment: What if there's a gap, e.g. no invoice_id 4?

Comment: Invoice id is from sequence. And i need display invoice in 3 column

Comment: If you found an answer, don't change your question. Add an answer and accept that. Otherwise this question will remain "open"

Comment: The answer you found for yourself will show 1, 2, 3 in the "first" row, then 2, 3, 4 in the "second" row, etc. Is that what you wanted? Also, why do you need to do this in SQL, and not in your reporting application?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using rownum & inline view of the same column to split them in columns. Then you have to make join. Your query will be like

```
select  g.empno, f.empno from (select  e.empno from emp e
where rownum < 3 or rownum >2)f, emp g
where g.empno = f.empno
and rownum < 3
```

This is just a direction for you not the exact answer. You can create your logic from here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found by myself

```
select *
from (
SELECT invoice_id, 
       LEAD (invoice_id,1) OVER (ORDER BY invoice_date) AS next_invoice ,
       LEAD (invoice_id,2) OVER (ORDER BY invoice_date) AS next_invoice2 
FROM invoice ORDER BY invoice_date)
where mod(rownum,3) = 0
```